# Проблема с файлами в ноде

Tags: node.js, шаблоны

Я запустил через ноду сервер, на запрос пользователя выдаю ему страницу-шаблон jade.

```
   !!! 5
    html
         head
            script(type='text/javascript', src='../js/jquery.js')
            script(type='text/javascript', src='../js/valid.js')
```

И с путями что-то не то, где находится корень сайта ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так понимаю, вы взялись за express. Путь для статики задается примерно так:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
```

В данном случае корнем для статики будет директория `static` в директории приложения.